# Is Bahamut still alive in the Forgotten Realms in 1489 DR?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

I was reading about Bahamut in the forgotten realms wiki, and in it it states that he died. However it also states that he is a god. So I'm curious, is Bahamut still alive or did he simply die on the mortal plane?

Comment: Related: [Where is Myrkul's return detailed?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/82643/19580), [Is Shaundakul still alive in 5e?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53985/19580)

Comment: Something I've personally noticed is that the FR wiki doesn't seem to have had 5e-based canon updates widely propagated through it, which may explain some discrepancies you see there. The Sundering, the 4e -> 5e lore event, shook up a lot of details about the gods that might not yet be reflected in the wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Bahamut is alive and well

On page 86 of the 5e monster manual, Bahamut is spoken of in the present tense.

> Tiamat's most hated enemy is Bahamut the Platinum Dragon, with whom
>   she shares control of the faith of dragonkind.

On page 298 of the Players Handbook, under "Nonhuman Deities" the first entry is:

> *Bahamut, dragon god of good* (Align *LG*, Domains *Life/War*, Symbol *Dragon's head in profile*)

PHB p.293 indicates that the table on p. 298. is shared by both FR & Greyhawk, so it should be valid for FR. (Credit to @CTWind)

The reports of his demise are premature, if you accept 5e D&D as a valid state of being.

---

(From comments under the question)

> you're asking if Bahamut is alive in 1489 DR? Is that the question? – @SevenSidedDie
>
> Yes Sevensideddie, that is correct. – @Bigbo Biggins

The campaign date of the Forgotten Realms 1491 DR coincides with the real-world year of 2015 (Princes of the Apocalypse campaign).  Per your comment, in terms of DR 1492 ... he's not dead (yet).

Comment: Possibly worth noting is that while the cited Nonhuman Deities table on PHB p.298 is separate from the Deities of the Forgotten Realms table, PHB p.293 states that said table is shared by both FR & Greyhawk and it should therefore be valid for FR. (Unfortunately, SCAG does not seem to go into the present state of Bahamut at all, and doesn't reference him in its deities tables)

Comment: @CTWind Good point